# Why light it is reflected by a mirror stays in a straight line?

Tags: reflection

When we reflect a beam of light using a mirror, then beam of light stays in a straight line. So what is the cause of the straight line.

[image]

**Here in this image light comes in a straight line and after getting reflected it stays in a straight line. Why? **

Comment: Why do you think it should be a curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Euclidean space, the shortest line connecting two points is a straight line. It's gonna take the path which requires the least time aka Fermat's least action principle.

If you want to prove why Snell's law holds, say you have $\theta_1$ angle from the left, $a$ height and $x$ distance from the normal, $\theta_2$ from the right, $b$ height and $d-x$ distance from the normal. Time it takes for light to travel the path

$$t=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{v}+\frac{\sqrt{b^2+(d-x)^2}}{v}$$

above statement tells us

$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{x}{v\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}-\frac{d-x}{v\sqrt{b^2+(d-x)^2}}=0$$

this is equivalent with

$$\frac{\sin(\theta_{1})}{v}=\frac{\sin(\theta_{2})}{v} \rightarrow \sin(\theta_1)=sin(\theta_2)$$

This is the well known law of reflection equation.